# How do I resolve this CORS error on Spotify Search API?

Tags: javascript, spotify

I am rather new to APIs in Javascript. I am attempting to connect to Spotify's APIs using the following code. I already have code that gets a valid token already.

```
  function searchApi() {
    const searchBox = window.document.getElementById("searchBox");
    const searchString = searchBox.value;

    fetch(searchUrl, {
      q: searchString,
      type: "artist",
      headers: {
        'Bearer': token
      }
    }).then(function (response){
      return response.json();
    }).then(function (data){
      console.log(data);
    })

  }
```

However, I am currently getting a CORS error I am unsure how to resolve.

```
Access to fetch at 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field bearer is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Does anyone know what I should do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this because the fetch request you send originates from a http site rather than a https site, i.e. it doesn't use ssl.

Comment: How can I resolve this error in my JS code?

Comment: Well, you could make sure you send the request from HTTPS. If that isn't an option, you might want to take a look at the cors package here: `https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors`. This is if you are using nodejs, which I'm not sure you are.

There are also articles out there explaining this CORS issue and how to circumvent it such as this one: `https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9`